# DropDown filled with AJAX does not postback its values?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an asp Dropdown that I fill at runtime on the client via ajax.

When I postback to my codebehind though it does not have any values and no selected value.

I could dump and parse the values into a hidden field but is there a better way?

Thanks

In code behind:

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    elemSchedule = ScheduleManager.GetSchedule(elemScheduleID);
    KezErrorList errors = new KezErrorList();

    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            int priority = int.Parse(ddlPriority.SelectedValue);
```

In frontend:

```
            fillPriorityList("#<%= ddlPriority.ClientID %>",
   $("#<%= txtID.ClientID %>").val(), $("#<%= ddlEmp.ClientID %>").val(),
             $("#<%= txtStartDate.ClientID %>").val(), $("#<%= txtPriority.ClientID %>").val());
```

Comment: Make sure the your dropdown is not having it's items re-created on the postback.

Comment: @Milo : I think the best way is as you said is to keep it some where like hidden field before doing the postback and use the value in the post back calls. Since at the time of rendering of the page the items was not created ,  i think there is no other way to access it from codebehind file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using the Updatepanel Ajax instead of jQuery Ajax and see if you are still facing the issue? I believe the data is out of sync  for the dropdown between the client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are using asp.net webforms) you need to make sure that you put the same values that you put on the client (via ajax) also on the server. Otherwise you would get the effect that you are describing.